# AWS architecture - sending object between lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have an object (JSON) that I need to API Call will trigger

- process and return the result as PDF in HTTP response
- store the initial object (JSON) to dbs (dynamoDB).

My first idea was create 2 lambda functions:

1. lambda would generate the PDF and send SNS message with object as JSON
2. lambda would read the SNS topic and store it to dbs

But seems SNS or SQS are not designed to send JSON in message.

1. Should I use Step Functions instead so I would call lambdas directly?
2. What do you think would be the best approach?
3. What is the best way to send objects between lambdas?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. When you say that you have an object, do you mean an S3 object (such as Word document)? And you want to create a PDF from that document. What do you mean by "store the initial object to dbs"? What is "dbs"? Is your client invoking this whole process somehow e.g. an API call via API Gateway, or it is going to be triggered by a file being uploaded to S3? By the way, you can send JSON messages using SQS and SNS but it's not sensible to try to send file contents, if that's what you're referring to when you say "SNS or SQS are not designed to send JSON".

Comment: I have updated the question based on your comments.
1. json object
2. dbs is dynamoDB (but it does not matter I guess whether it is MySQL or anything else)
3. API Call will trigger Lambda. (I thought its obvious, sorry)
4. SNS, SQS accepts string only so yes I can stringify the JSON. I read it somewhere it is not the best approach.
I appreciate asking the question instead giving negative feedback ...

Comment: OK, so the object is a JSON payload. Why not a single Lambda function that is invoked with the JSON payload and a) writes the payload to DynamoDB and then b) simply generates a PDF (whatever the PDF represents)? Why do you think two Lambda invocations would be preferred?

Comment: Yes that is possible without problem.
I am trying to split it as much as possible to provide small functions.
Since one generate the PDF and the other stores the json.

Comment: If the initial Lambda is invoked from an API client via API Gateway then wouldn't it be problematic for you to decouple the PDF production from the DynamoDB persistence? Wouldn't your API client want to know that *both* had succeeded? That's harder to do if you decouple them (it can be done, but it's harder).

Comment: You are right. It sound more reasonable to handled it under the same lambda.
Thank you.

Comment: @hybaken Rather than "returning" the PDF, one option is to store the PDF in Amazon S3, then return a URL to the object. It would also be more efficient and cost-effective to store a _reference_ to the PDF in the database, rather than storing the actual PDF in the database.

Comment: I am not storing the actual pdf in database, just the values that generate it.